# PHP - Convert GMT Timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm receiving some data from an HTTP POST which includes what is labelled a GMT Timestamp:

```
<gmt_timestamp>201308031525</gmt_timestamp>
```

I then need to take this timestamp and convert it to this format:

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM
```

So far I've been trying this:

```
$ts = $_GET['timestamp'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdHi', $ts);
$fmTimestamp = $date->format('m/d/Y h:i:s A');
```

but that generates a "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object" for the 2nd line. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if you debug `$date`, you will find the variable is null. `createFromFormat()` fails to create a date when given input is incorrect, thus return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in this line:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdHi', $ts);
```

You need an uppercase `Y` for the year:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', $ts);
```

A lowercase `y` indicates "A two digit representation of a year", whereas you need `Y` ("A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits"). See the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

You also need to set the timezone before you begin:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

(PHP does have a `GMT` timezone, but [it shouldn't be used](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php). `UTC` behaves the same as `GMT` within PHP.)

**Edit**

To get your desired output format of:

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM
```

you need to do:

```
$fmTimestamp = $date->format('m/d/Y H:i');
```

Also, since you're "receiving some data from an HTTP POST", you need to use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`:

```
$ts = $_POST['timestamp'];
```

So the complete code is:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$ts = $_POST['timestamp'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', $ts);
$fmTimestamp = $date->format('m/d/Y H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple stupid.

```
$input = $_GET['timestamp']; // 201308031525
$year = (int)substr($input,0,4);
$month = (int)substr($input,4,2);
$date = (int)substr($input,6,2);
$hour = (int)substr($input,8,2);
$minute = (int)substr($input,10);

$date_obj = new DateTime($year . '-' . $month . '-' . $date .' ' . $hour . ':' . $minute);
echo $date_obj->format('m/d/Y h:i:s A');
```

and the output is:

```
08/03/2013 03:25:00 PM
```

Comment: Are you saying that an additional 5 lines of code to extract the date and time elements and cast them to `int`s, plus concatenating all those elements together into a string for the `DateTime` constructor, is "simpler" than `DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHi', $ts);`?

Comment: Just another approach, relax.

Answer (score -1):

You are not instantiating the object you are trying to use.

Try this approach instead:

```
$date = new DateTime;
$date->createFromFormat('ymdHi', $ts);
$fmTimestamp = $date->format('m/d/Y h:i:s A');
```

This is untested, just saying ...

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a `DateTime` object, because `createFromFormat()` is a static method.